# TSQL - Return duplicate rows with highest value and longest date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have got a list of staff who are contractors and it includes duplicates as some work on multiple contracts at the same time.  I need to find the row with the most hours for that person and secondly with the end date furthest away (if the hours is the same). I guess this is the **Current main contract**.  I also need to make sure the Date From and the Date to is in between the current date - how can this be done?

```
+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| ContractID | PersonID | Name | Hours | Date From  |  Date To   |
+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+------------+
|          8 |        1 | John |    30 | 20/02/2018 | 26/02/2018 |
|          8 |        2 | Paul |     5 | 20/02/2018 | 26/02/2018 |
|          7 |        3 | John |     7 | 20/02/2018 | 26/02/2018 |
+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

In the above example, I would need to bring back the John – 30hours and the Paul 5 Hours row.  PS - The PersonID is different for each row but the "Name" is the same for the person if on multiple contracts.

Thanks

Comment: For the second part, use:

select *, case when getdate() between [Date From] and [Date To] then 'Current' else 'Not Current' end from tablename

For the first part, try:

select PersonID, max(hours) as hours, max([Date To]) as [Date To] from [Table] group by PersonID

Answer (score 1):

One approach is simply to use `exists` with appropriate ordering logic:

```
select c.*
from contracts c
where c.contractid = (select top 1 c2.contractid
                      from contracts c2
                      where c2.name = c.cname and
                            getdate() >= c2.datefrom and
                            getdate() < c2.dateto
                      order by c2.hours desc, c2.dateto desc
                     );
```

You can put similar logic into a window function:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c.name order by c.hours desc, c.dateto desc) as seqnum
      from contracts c
      where getdate() >= c.dateto and getdate() < c.datefrom 
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the full row, I'd do somehthing like this:

```
with
rankedByHours as (
select
  ContractID, 
  PersonID,
  Name,
  Hours,
  [Date From],
  [Date To],
  row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by Hours desc) as RowID
from
  Contracts  
)
select
  ContractID, 
  PersonID,
  Name,
  Hours,
  [Date From],
  [Date To],
  case 
    when getdate() between [Date From] and [Date To] then 'Current'
    when getdate() < [Date From] then 'Not Started'
    else 'Expired'
  end as ContractStatus  
from
  RankedByHours
where
  RowID = 1;
```

Use the CTE to inject a row_number() sorting all rows by your sort criteria, then select out the top one in the main body.  It can be easily extended to also capture your farthest-out end date.